# attempting to specialize template function with non-type argument in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization, non-type-template-parameter

I have a templated function, which takes an array reference as a parameter:

```
template<typename T, int arrSize>
void foo(T (&pArr)[arrSize]) {
    cout << "base template function" << endl;
}
```

I want to specialize this function for C-strings:

```
template<const char *, int arrSize>
void foo(const char * (&pArr)[arrSize]) {
    cout << "specialized template function" << endl;
}
```

I try to instantiate the base and the specialization:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    float nums[] = {0.3, 0.2, 0.11};
    const char *words[] = {"word1", "word2"};
    foo(nums);
    foo(words);
}
```

But I only seem to get the base instantiation:

```
./foo
base template function
base template function
```

I have compiled this on a Mac using clang++ with -std=c++17.

Comment: There's no need to use specialisations here, just use an overload. You can't use a specialisation as your signature doesn't match the original function

Comment: Remove the `const char *` template parameter. Also this is overloading, not specializing a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that the 2nd **overloaded** function template that you've provided has a non-type template parameter of type `const char*` that cannot be deduced from the function parameter. So to call this overloaded version we have to explicitly provide the template argument corresponding to this non-type parameter.

To **solve** this just remove the first non-type template parameter as shown [below](https://onlinegdb.com/WNq4c2GW6):

```
template<typename T, int arrSize>
void foo(T (&pArr)[arrSize]) {
    std::cout << "base template function" << std::endl;
}
//overload for C-strings
template< int arrSize>
void foo(const char (&pArr)[arrSize]) {
    std::cout << "single C-string overloaded version" << std::endl;
}
//overload for array of pointers to C-strings
template<std::size_t arrSize>
void foo(const char*(&pArr)[arrSize])
{
    std::cout<<" array of pointers to C-string version"<<std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    float nums[] = {0.3, 0.2, 0.11};
    const char words[] = {"word1"};
    const char* wordPtrs[] = {"word1", "word2"};
    
    foo(nums); //calls base
    foo(words);//calls single C-string version
    foo(wordPtrs);//calls array of pointers to C-string version
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WNq4c2GW6)

Also note that function templates cannot be partially specialized but they can be fully specialized or they can be overloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
template<int arrSize>
void foo(const char * (&pArr)[arrSize]);
```

You were defining an overload expecting a non-deducible `char const*` non-type parameter.

Comment: It's *still* an overload. There is no instead.

Comment: No instead anymore.